# Where should I perform custom application initialization steps in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core framework gives us two well defined places for initialization:
1. the `Startup.ConfigureServices()` method for registering DI services 
2. the `Startup.Configure()` method for configuration of middleware pipeline

But what about other initialization steps specific to my web application? Where should those go, especially if they have dependencies that need to be injected?

For example I need to initialize database ORM based on connection string which is specified in configuration file appsettings.json. So this initialization code has dependency on `IConfiguration` and perhaps other custom services that are registered into DI container during `Startup.ConfigureServices()`

So as per recommendations from these articles:

- https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2019/02/14/net-core-opinion-7-startup-responsibilities.aspx
- https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2019/03/07/net-core-opinion-10-move-more-code-out-of.aspx

I tried to encapsulate initialization logic in separate classes and then to create extension method for `IWebHostBuilder` that would execute this code, but how can I make framework inject `IConfiguration` and other custom dependencies into this extension methods? Also, can I be sure that this code will be executed after `Startup.ConfigureServices()` when all dependencies are registered?

Is there some better or recommended way to perform this kind of tasks?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can add an extension method for `IWebHost` (instead of `IWebHostBuilder`) and then use [`IWebHost.Services`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhost.services?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for resolving services. Here's an example of how to retrieve `IConfiguration`:

```
public static class WebHostExtensions
{
    public static IWebHost SomeExtension(this IWebHost webHost)
    {
        var config = webHost.Services.GetService<IConfiguration>();

        // Your initialisation code here.
        // ...

        return webHost;
    }
}
```

Usage of this extension method would look something like this:

```
CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
    .Build()
    .SomeExtension()
    .Run();
```

If you need an `async` version of `SomeExtension`, you can split up the chaining above and `await` the extension method. Here's what that might look like:

```
public static async Task SomeExtensionAsync(this IWebHost webHost)
{
    var config = webHost.Services.GetService<IConfiguration>();

    // Your initialisation code here with awaits.
    // ...
}
```

Usage looks something like this:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var webHost = CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
        .Build();

    await webHost.SomeExtensionAsync();

    webHost.Run();
}
```

> Also, can I be sure that this code will be executed after `Startup.ConfigureServices()` when all dependencies are registered?

With the approach I've outlined above, the answer here is yes.

---

Note that `IWebHost.Services` represents the *root* `IServiceProvider`, which will not support resolving *scoped* instances. `IConfiguration` is a singleton, so this isn't an issue for that, but if you have *scoped* dependencies, you'll need to create an explicit scope inside of your extension method.

Comment: thanks for the explanation @Kirk Larkin. I was wondering what is the best practice if an error/exception occurs in this 'user-defined' initialization process?

Comment: @povke I'm not sure about a "best practice" here, but I'd expect some kind of `try/catch` around the call to `SomeExtensionAsync` (or even the entire `Main` body). This could log the exception out to a third-party service, for example, to notify you that the app failed to start. Alternatively, whatever runs your app might ship any output it sees on `stderr` to another service, to notify you in a similar fashion.

Comment: yes, thank you @Kirk Larkin I understand that part, but I am more curious about what should be done with the webhost? Should it be started or just opted-out from the app? I know it depends on the hosting environment, and what got me worried/confused is this [topic](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22507). Do you have any input on this? :)

Comment: @povke I've not experienced that problem myself, but I think I'd skip the host and let the process exit with a non-zero status code. I expect the solution might be different for different deployment scenarios.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will probably have to test both scenarios on Azure to see how it behaves

Answer (score 5):

In `Program.cs` you have the following code for your `Main` method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
```

After the `Build()` part has run, you have a fully configured host. As such, you can simply do something like the following:

```
var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

// do something with host

host.Run();
```

The host has a member, `Services`, which is an instance of `IServiceProvider`, so you can pull any services you need from that, i.e.

```
var config = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
```

Just bear in mind that at this point, there is no inherent scope, so if you need scoped services, you'll need to create one:

```
using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var myScopedService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyScopedService>();
    // do something with myScopedService
}
```